# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

my project structure is something like this :

```
project_root/
├── my_package/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── src/
├   ├    ├── my_module.py
└── tests/
    ├── test_module.py
```

in test_module I am trying to import my module like this : `from my_package.src import my_module as my_module` .but I am getting error like : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'
I am using pytest to run this

Comment: Are you aware of `PYTHONPATH`, `sys.path` and/or setup tools?